# Theorem 1.9 in Folland's Real Analysis

Tags: measure-theory

I have come across a proof of Theorem 1.9 in Folland's *Real Analysis* from [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1802044/real-analysis-folland-theorem-1-9-extention-of-a-measure-to-a-complete-measure?rq=1).

> **Theorem 1.9** Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\overline{\mathcal X}$ be the [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure#Construction_of_a_complete_measure) of $\mathcal X$ with respect to $\mu$. There is a unique measure $\overline \mu$ on $(X, \overline{\mathcal X})$ such that $\mu = \overline \mu|_{\mathcal X}$. We also have $\overline \mu$ is complete.

My below attempt seems more concise than that from the other thread. Could you check if I made some subtle mistakes?

---

**Proof** Let $\mu^*$ be the [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Method_I) induced from $\mu$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the collection of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets, i.e., those sets $A \subseteq X$ such that
$$
\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A) +\mu^*(E\cap A^c) \quad \forall E\subset X.
$$

I [proved previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608028/the-construction-from-outer-measure-of-the-completion-of-a-measure-space) that $\mu = \mu^*|_{\mathcal X}$, $\overline{\mathcal X} \subset \mathcal M$, and $\mu^*|_{\overline{\mathcal X}}$ is a complete measure. This proves the existence part. Let's prove the uniqueness part. Let $\mathcal N$ be the collection of all subsets of $\mu$-null subsets of $X$, i.e.,
$$
\mathcal N := \{A \subset X :\exists N \in \mathcal X \text{ such that } A \subset N \text{ and } \mu (N)=0\}.
$$

Let $\nu$ be a measure on $(X, \overline{\mathcal X})$ such that $\mu =  \nu|_{\mathcal X}$. Fix $A \in \overline{\mathcal X}$. Then $A = B \cup C$ for some $B \in \mathcal X$ and $C \in \mathcal N$. We have
$$
\mu(B)=\nu(B) \le \nu(A) \le \nu (B)+\nu(C) = \nu(B)+0 = \mu(B).
$$

It follows that $\nu(A) = \mu(B)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Cannot find any flaw in this. But I would rather end with:$$\overline{\mu}(A)=\mu(B)=\nu(A)$$...this completes the proof.

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much for your verification!